# HttpClient via BSON to RESTful API

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, bson

I have tried post object from window client to a controller.

It can be receive Test Object but `id` and `id2` is `0` and `null` value.

Did I miss some config?

```
public class Test
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id2 { get; set; }
}
```

//webapiconfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

window client

```
private async void Form1_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58716/");

        // Set the Accept header for BSON.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

        var aa = new Test()
        {
            id = 2,
            id2="3333"
        };

        // POST using the BSON formatter.
        MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        var result = await client.PostAsync("Report/Test", aa, bsonFormatter);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

}
```

web server

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public void Test(Test aa)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably your web server doesn't speak BSON.  However, without more details about your Web setup its impossible to suggest a remedy.

Comment: Your binary on client must be the same received on server, see hash SHA1 to test, use use 'application/octet-stream' to transport, and get  on server the original binary to compare.

Answer (score 0):

`Register` is configuring for a `ApiController` while the shown `ReportController` is a MVC `Controller`

Update Target controller to derive from the correct type and have the necessary attributes.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Report")]
public class ReportController : ApiController {
    //POST api/Report/Test
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody]Test model) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            //...

            return Ok();
        }
        return BasRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

And update the client to send to the correct URL

```
//...

 // POST using the BSON formatter.
MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
var result = await client.PostAsync("api/Report/Test", aa, bsonFormatter);
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: @cheuklaw Glad to help

Comment: @cheuklaw if this resolves the original issue [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/356823)